# Dexcom API Oauth2 Fails on Callback

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, authlib

I'm trying to get a simple Flask app working with Dexcom's sandbox API (https://developer.dexcom.com). I'm having difficulty getting authorization through OAuth2.

I registered my app on their website and have the client_id and client_secret. I also set the callback to http://127.0.0.1:5000/authorize

The app is able to redirect to Dexcom's authorization page. The problem is once the authorize button is pushed the app crashes on the callback with an Internal Server Error. The authorize code is visible in the browser URL though. Below is what shown in the terminal.

authlib.integrations.base_client.errors.OAuthError: invalid_client: invalid_client

In the browser debugger I do not see a request with the authorize code and client_secret.

Below is the code.

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, redirect, session
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key='something_random_123'
oauth = OAuth(app)
dexcom = oauth.register(
    name='dexcom',
    client_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    client_secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    access_token_url='https://sandbox-api.dexcom.com/v2/oauth2/token',
    acess_token_params=None,
    authorize_url='https://sandbox-api.dexcom.com/v2/oauth2/login',
    authorize_params=None,
    api_base_url='https://sandbox-api.dexcom.com/v2/oauth2/',
    client_kwargs={'scope':'offline_access'}
)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello'

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    dexcom = oauth.create_client('dexcom')
    redirect_uri = url_for('authorize', _external=True)
    return dexcom.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)
 
@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    dexcom = oauth.create_client('dexcom')
    token = dexcom.authorize_access_token()     # CRASHES HERE
    return redirect('/authorized')

@app.route('/authorized')
def authorized():
    return 'Successfully authorized'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = "1"
    app.run()
```

Comment: Probably not the issue, but you have a typo: `authroize_params`

Comment: Fixed the typo, but yes not the root of the issue.